# What is a word, preferably a noun, referring to a liquid that begins with M?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am seizing up on this point while making an alliteration.

All I found was:

- Moist - Refers to property of another material (a surface, the air, etc.) that involves liquid not the liquid itself
- Mellifluous - Seems to refer more to liquid-like proprieties of sound then to liquid.
- Mucus - Very specific to biological fluids, and inclusive of semifluids.

There is some tolerance with usage, but I image it as follows:

- Vivian held the chilled vial of **** over the open chamber.
- A roiling **** bubbled and stewed in the cauldron.
- The magnificent mixture of mellow ****(s) merged meekly with the murky mire.
- A multi-chamber canister full of ****(s) was plugged into the side of the device, to fuel the reaction.

**EDIT:**

The story so far:

> Meticulously modeling and manipulating microbial monsters to manufacture microliters of immiscible mass, mileage for our multitudes of magnificent machines.

The 'im' irks me. Is it viable? Is there a better option?

The substance in this case... fuel... is definitively not miscible.

Comment: Perhaps *milk*?

Comment: Milk is the closest I've got so far. I didn't want it to be quite that specific, as it distracts.

Comment: How liquidy does it need to be?  *Mush* seems like an option if a little viscosity is allowed.

Comment: You have such a mixture in your examples, adjectives and nouns. Also only one has alliteration. Can you pin this down a bit more? Also do you want a pleasant substance, a nasty substance?

Comment: ***Miscible*** (which can be a noun as well as an adjective) invariably refers to *liquids*.

Comment: "Melted substance" certainly means liquid... (a last resort maybe)

Comment: I agree with @FumbleFingers

Comment: @FumbleFingers I love it! It is uniquely hard to use in this case though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thinking along the lines of *bolus*, there's

> [***mass***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mass) -a body of coherent matter, usually of indefinite shape and often of considerable size:
>
> *a mass of dough.*

Comment: I don't get it... :( How does *mass* fit the OP's requirements? A *mass of liquid* possibly, but *mass* alone does not suggest liquid.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I tried to fill in the blank on bullet point three, as it was the most alliterative.  There is surrounding context there that makes it more apt than it might seem

Answer (score 3):

Magma, malt, malted, malt liquor, malted milk, maple syrup, marinade, marinara, marine, martini, mead, ....

... meltwater, menhaden oil, menses, mercury, mescal, molten, molotov cocktail, moisture, mouthwash, ....

Comment: +1 Thank you for the creativity. We are in search of a chimera.

Comment: @bib What? 'Chimera' doesn't start with an 'm'.

Comment: "Kinda stumped for M-words, are you?"  he said facetiously.  Oh, and menses is particularly, uh, gross! Don

Comment: @Mitch:  check this out:  http://img.tfd.com/hm/JPG/A5chimera.jpg

Comment: @Mitch Sorry, I meant a *mhimera*.

Comment: @bib, chimera, mhimera...it's a fluid word.

Answer (score 2):

**molasses**

> : a thick, brown, sweet liquid that is made from raw sugar [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/molasses)

**mucilage**

> : any of various, usu. liquid, preparations of gum, glue, or the like,
>   used as an adhesive. [Random House Kernerman Webster's College
>   Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mucilage)

**metheglin**

> : a beverage typically made of fermented honey and water; **mead**.
>   [The American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/metheglin#Sc8mAHJxYTRZgcwK.99)

Comment: Mucilage is the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Something that has *melted* has become liquefied by heat (a liquid). This refers to any  substance with a melting point (anything really). As a noun, this would be a **[melt.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/melt)** Per *dictionary.com* ...

> something that is melted.